# Display LinkedHashMap in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a map in jsp

```
<s:set name="answer" value="#{0:'No', 1:'Yes', 2:'Maybe' }"/>
```

How to access the answer map using the key?

```
<s:property value="?"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: Sorry, mis-read on mobile device.*

```
#theMap[theKey]
```

Variables created with `<s:set>` are named variables and must be accessed using the leading `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<s:set name="answer" value="#{'0':'No', '1':'Yes', '2':'Maybe' }"/>
   <s:property value="#answer['1']"/>
```

Comment: Quoting the keys isn't necessary (and if the intent is to mirror an enum or DB int field, is a bit of a pain on the action side).

Comment: @Dave Agree. Quotes can be removed and it will work fine, treating it like int.